# Pasar datos de un jTextField a un arreglo

Tags: java, array, split, jtextfield

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de java basándome en un código en c que ya tenia hecho, pero estoy teniendo problemas con el introducirle a un arreglo el valor que entra por jTextField.

Este es el arreglo en el que deseo meter los datos que entran por el jTextField

```
    private String [] letras = "".split(""); //
```

el dato que entra por el jTextField debe entrar a el arreglo para que me separe cada dato como una cadena

o sea que si yo en el jTextField meto  "JK"
el arreglo lo jale y lo almacene asi

```
    (java.lang.String[]) [j, k]
```

He estado haciendo varias pruebas y cambios a lo largo del código y no logro hacer que el jTextField me jale los datos y los ponga en el arreglo, no entiendo que me esta haciendo falta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que puede ayudarte en tu caso:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String textField = "JK"; // Variable que simula el valor del jtextField
    String[] array = new String[textField.length()]; // array para guardar los datos

    //Recorremos la palabra que llega del jtextField y la guardamos en el array caracter a caracter
    for(int i = 0; i < textField.length(); i++){
        array[i] = String.valueOf(textField.charAt(i));
    }

    //Recorremos el array y mostramos cada caracter separado por comas
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(i != array.length-1)
            System.out.print(array[i]+",");
        else
            System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```